# How to find out how long a c++ application is running on WINDOWS?

Tags: c++, windows, time, resources

I want to write a C\C++ function that returns how long the application is running.
How can I do it on WINDOWS?

BTW, I don't want to use GetSystemTime because the user can set the clock and I don't want to use GetTickCount because it takes too much from the OS resources (The application is going to call the function frequently).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this your own process or [another](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683223%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Comment: It seems that this could help you:

http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/26759/best-way-to-get-elapsed-time-in-miliseconds-in-windows

Comment: It is my process. Thanks for the link. I see that I can use also QueryPerformanceCounter but which way won't raise the CPU? I don't care too much about the resolution. I need to call this function every 5-10 msec and when I'm using GetTickCount, the OS is stuck...

Answer (score 0):

What about WM_TIMER? I think that could be helpful to build such a function..